# Locating pre-emigration records in Ireland for Peter Starrs born abt 1836 and relations?

Tags: 19th-century, census-records, birth-records, 18th-century, ireland

I am trying to find a Peter Starrs born in Ireland in the 1830's, most likely about 1836. He most likely emigrated alone to the U.S. about 1855.

From US Census Records presented in [Finding record of Peter J Starrs in USA prior to 1870 Census?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8084/finding-record-of-peter-j-starrs-in-usa-prior-to-1870-census) I believe that the Peter Starrs I seek was born about 1836 in Ireland. Most likely Northern Ireland as most Starrs seem to come from there.

His estimated year of birth is different from 1870 (says 1829-1830) to 1880 (says 1836) census records (but it is him).

His wife, Mary Ann Starrs (McDowell-maiden name) died in July 6th, 1880 in NYC.
http://search.findmypast.ie/record?id=us%2fbmd%2firishdeathnotices%2f34439 says that she was born in the County of Cavan.

I also found a marriage notice for a Peter Starrs to a Maggie Veane in Oct 1880 in NYC which lists the names of their parents, but **I have not been able to determine this is a second marriage for the same Peter Starrs**
https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:24SM-25F

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding record of Peter J Starrs in USA prior to 1870 Census?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8084/finding-record-of-peter-j-starrs-in-usa-prior-to-1870-census)

Comment: @vervet No, it's not a duplicate. One question deals with only records in the USA after he immigrated to New York. The other, with the family line (parents, siblings) in Ireland - tracing the family line in Ireland.

Comment: I think it is too early to try and answer this question with any confidence because, unless you can "trace" Peter's translocation from Ireland to the US, it will be very difficult to establish the identity of any/many boys/men named Peter Starrs recorded in Ireland with your `Peter J Starrs`.  I recommend focussing on US Census and Immigration records first which we are doing in http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8084/finding-record-of-peter-j-starrs-in-usa-prior-to-1870-census

Comment: @vervet I'm thinking that this can be treated as a separate question if it can be edited so that it is clearly about finding candidates for any boys/men named Peter Starrs born in about the 1830s in Ireland, and "disappearing" from Ireland by about 1855.  This would make no assumption about it being the same Peter Starrs that Erin is asking about in the other question but any answers may help build the case towards suspecting/concluding that they are the same person later.

Comment: This is true, but the two questions are extremely closely related. I suspect you will be much closer to answering the Ireland question when you work out Mr Starr's early origins in the USA. I just don't feel it's possible to give this question a useful answer, because your USA info is minimal at present and, even if we identify a candidate in Ireland, it would be very diffficult to know if it's your man. Nevertheless, I will withdraw my 'duplicate' vote.

Comment: If this were my own question, I would start an answer that lists all the Peter Starrs that *could* be your Peter Starr, and say why you have eliminated any, or why you may favour a particular one.  That way, instead of simply retracing your steps potential answerers will be looking for what you may have missed, and then be able to post their own answer.  I think it is fine to answer your own questions here, even if they may start as only a partial answer.

Comment: From http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8084/finding-record-of-peter-j-starrs-in-usa-prior-to-1870-census it seems that Peter's wife was born in County Cavan.  To me this would make the chance that Peter was also born there slightly higher than him being born in any other Irish county.  He may have only met Mary in the US, but my understanding is that often immigrants arrived with others from the same area, and tended to mix initially with those from similar backgrounds.

Comment: @PolyGeo  I am an amateur on this site so I apologize if I have made mistakes with the protocol usually used.  That said, thank you for all the help!

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes, regarding Mary's home county, you may be on to something! I have never been able to verify Peter's immigration and if he came alone and married in U.S. or came with his wife. I do know that Mary's sister Jane McDowell also came to the U.S. and at least one of her brother (last name Cunningham). Her parents George McDowell and Eleanor Caffrey - Cunningham- McDowell, I have no record of in the U.S that I have yet found. Although all cesus records that I have found for Peter Starrs say that his 3 boys were born in the U.S., there is a disputing article in an Irish newspaper that

Comment: reports the 3 boys came over from Ireland very young. The (many) articles are about a fight over an inheritance from a half brother (James Walter Cunningham) of Mary Starrs that was left to her only surviving son, Charles M Starrs in 1901. So, I have never been sure if I should believe the census or the article as I have not been able to find birth records on any of the 3 boys.

Comment: If there is a chance that any of the three boys were born in Ireland, with the family emigrating later, the focus of this question (while it has no answers posted) could be re-worked, or another asked, to seek either a marriage record for Peter and Mary, or a birth record for one of their sons.  If Mary came from County Cavan then that is where I would start looking for her Marriage Record.